# Is is worth to use fulltext search in postgres for short texts like names, username, email?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I started to look into Postgres fulltext search features. But when indexing things like email addresses I'm having some issues with the tokenizer.

First of all the textsearch seems to be for longer text, where searching for whole words is fine. When my email address is indexed as a single word, it's only possible to search for prefixes. But a common case is to search for `company` to find `user@some-company.org` where the default textsearch index fails.

I have the feeling that falling back to `'user@some-company.org' ILIKE '%company%'` would be the better option.

The question is: Does anyone got a good configuration for the textsearch for short fields like email addresses, usernames, etc. to replase ILIKE seaches, or isn't it worth the effort and text search is really just meant to be used on longer texts?

Answer (score 3):

For such cases a trigram index is more suitable:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON atable USING gin
   (email gin_trgm_ops);
```

That will support your substring search.

This is also useful for searching names by similarity, which is a frequent requirement. The similarity operator `%` is also supported by this index.